# Executar DELETE somente quando retornar o SELECT

Tags: c#, query, microsoft-access, oledb

Tenho uma rotina onde atualizo a base de dados local com os dados de outra base.

Simplesmente executo um **DELETE** e em seguida um **INSERT INTO tblX (SELECT * FROM tblY (tblY é uma tabela vinculada))**, como abaixo.

O problema é que há um tempo entre o **DELETE** e o **INSERT** pois o **SELECT** demora muito tempo em alguns casos e eu queria diminuir ao máximo a possibilidade de o usuário solicitar registro de uma tabela que esteja no meio desse processamento.

Gostaria de saber se há algum mecanimo para que eu realize o **DELETE** somente quando o **SELECT** retornar.

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal());

conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" DELETE * FROM tblClienteContato; ", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new OleDbCommand(" INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
                       " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após testar as opções da resposta do Ismael e obter o retorno: "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported", acredito por se tratar do MS Access, acabei criando uma tabela temporária local para receber os dados da rede e depois transferir para a tabela definitiva, assim sendo, a transferência entre tabelas locais ocorre de maneira quase que instantânea.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que utilize Transações para efetuar essa sequência de comandos. Desta forma, você irá garantir um acesso único a tabela:

[**OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6yx87ys5(v=vs.110).aspx)
Inicia uma transação no banco de dados com a possibilidade de especificar o tipo de isolamento da transação.

[**Modo de Isolamento**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6yx87ys5(v=vs.110).aspx)
  - [IsolationLevel.Serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) = Impede que outros usuários atualizem ou insiram linhas no intervalo de está sendo alterado até que a transação seja concluída.

**Código**

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal())) {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbTransaction transaction = null;

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    // Abre a conexão e inicia a transação
    try {
        conn.Open();

        // Inicia uma transação
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM tblClienteContato";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //nesse meio tempo, NINGUÉM poderá efetuar qualquer operação na tabela tblClienteContato até que a transação seja finalizada

        cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
                          " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Efetiva a transação
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //exibe no console o erro
        try {
            // Se der algum erro (no delete ou insert) desfaz as alterações
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch {

        }
    }
    //Aqui a conexão já estará fechada 
}
```

**Leitura altamente recomendada**
[Mensagem de erro "Contagem de bloqueios de compartilhamento excedida..." durante o processamento de uma transação grande](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/815281/-file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded-error-message-during-large-transaction-processing)

[Transações e simultaneidade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/777e5ebh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Olá Ismael, estou recebendo essa mensagem quando executo o BeginTransaction: "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported".

Comment: Retire o IsolationLevel. Deixe apenas `conn.BeginTransaction();`

Comment: Funcionou, porém tenho o problema de o usuário não poder sequer fazer uma consulta. Preciso que a consulta fique disponível durante esse processo.

Comment: Dos diferentes tipos de isolamento, temos que encontrar o ideal para este cenário. O Serializable que informei, permitiria a leitura nas demais partes da tabela, como não é suportado (precisa se investigar) use o meio de isolamento que permite a leitura dos dados limpos - ReadCommitted. Se quiser permitir ler mesmo a parte que está sendo alterada, utilize o ReadUncommitted.

Comment: Acredito que essa seria a melhor opção porém recebi a mensagem "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported" para os outros tipos de transaction, deve ser o Access. Acabei criando tabelas temporárias.

Obrigado Ismael.

Answer (score 0):

O comando apos o método "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" só sera executado depois que o método  ExecuteNonQuery obter a resposta da base de dados, então você pode usar o "try/catch" é fazer o rollback se tiver alguma exceção.

```
Try {
    conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexaoPainelGerencialLocal());

    conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" DELETE * FROM tblClienteContato; ", conn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(" INSERT INTO tblClienteContato " +
                       " SELECT * FROM tblClienteContatoVinculada;", conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   // comando de delete aqui...
}
catch (SqlException odbcEx) {
   // erro na sql...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   // erro no driver erro...
}
```

Comment: Cara, não entendi a idéia.